# setState for a 2 level nested array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this array of object. `console.log(this.state.zones)` will print

```
[
  {
    "name": "Zone 1",
    "cameras": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Zone 2",
    "cameras": [
      {
        "device_id": 123,
        "entrance_name": "East Gate",
        "name": "SA-PCS-010",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to add a property of checked with the value of true or false, I tried below attempt.

```
this.setState({
  zones: [{
    ...this.state.zones,
      cameras: [{
        ...this.state.zones[this.state.selectedZoneOnMenu].cameras.map(
          o => ({...o, checked: o.device_id === camera_id ? true : false
          })
        )
      }]
  }]
})
```

assume `this.state.selectedZoneOnMenu` is 1 and `camera_id` is `'device_id'` is 123, why above setState failed? I got error of cameras of undefined when re-render.

Comment: For nested state its better to use ImmutableJS. Your code will be much clear

Answer (score 0):

You are using setting the state incorrectly, as the spread operator syntax is not at the right places. Try this

```
this.setState({
  zones: [ ...this.state.zones.slice(0, this.state.selectedZoneOnMenu), {
      ...this.state.zones[this.state.selectedZoneOnMenu],
      cameras: [
        ...this.state.zones[this.state.selectedZoneOnMenu].cameras.map(
          o => ({...o, checked: o.id === camera_id ? true : false
          })
        )]
  }, ...this.state.zones.slice(this.state.selectedZoneOnMenu + 1)]
})
```

However you state are deeply nested and it would make sense for you to use [`ImmutableJS`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) for your states or use [`immutability-helper npm package`](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html)

Comment: why use slice here? I don't get it. Especially this.state.selectedZoneOnMenu + 1

Comment: slice is needed here because you want to modify only one element of the array so you are keeping the other object before and after that as it is and replacing the object that you want to modify

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional `setState` to prevent mutating and also in my opinion your code would be much more clearer to read.

**Example**

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const zones = Object.assign({}, prevState.zones);
  const { selectedZoneOnMenu } = prevState;
  zones[selectedZoneOnMenu].cameras = zones[selectedZoneOnMenu].cameras.map((camera) => (
    Object.assign({}, camera, { checked: (camera.device_id === camera_id) })
  ));
  return { zones };
});
```